# Does this notion of the "directed area" of a closed curve in $\mathbb R^3$ have a standard name?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, differential-geometry, terminology

Given an oriented surface $\Omega$ in $\mathbb R^3$, consider the quantity $\mathbf A(\Omega)=\int_\Omega\hat n\,\mathrm dA$. We may call this the "directed area" of the surface because, when $\Omega$ is planar, $\mathbf A$ is parallel to its normal and has magnitude equal to the area of $\Omega$.

As it turns out, Stokes' theorem implies that $\mathbf A$ depends only on the boundary of $\Omega$; any other surface with the same boundary and orientation has the same directed area. So really, we are talking about directed areas of oriented closed *curves* in $\mathbb R^3$. Given an oriented closed curve $\Gamma$, we can construct any surface whose boundary is $\Gamma$ and compute its directed area. For convenience we may take the surface to be a cone with its vertex at the origin, and thereby obtain
$$\mathbf A(\Gamma)=\frac12\oint_\Gamma\mathbf r\times\mathrm d\mathbf r.$$

It seems like this should be a useful quantity. It determines, for example, the flux enclosed by the curve due to any constant vector field $\mathbf v$ as $\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf A$. But I have never seen it discussed in any text. Does it have a standard name, and is it ever useful in practice?

Comment: Something like a trivector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [vector area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_area); a vector whose components are given by signed area of the coordinate projections of the surface.

In addition to the reference given on Wikipedia, see *Linear Algebra via Exterior Products* by Sergei Winitzki (p.72-73). Also, there is a related question [How can area be a vector?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14165/how-can-area-be-a-vector) on Physics.SE.